# disabled key not working in angular project

Tags: angular

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
     <p>
      <label for="username">User Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" formControlName="userName"><br>
      <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.userName.valid && loginForm.controls.userName.dirty">
           invalied username! 
      </span>
     </p> 
      <p><label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" formControlName="passWord"><br>
      </p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Enter</button>
    </form>
  </div>



import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log-in',
  templateUrl: './log-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-in.component.css']
})
export class LogInComponent {

  loginForm=new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl(' ',[Validators.required]),
    passWord: new FormControl(' ',[Validators.required]),
  })

  onSubmit()
{
 console.log(this.loginForm.value);
}

}
```

this is my code i create a login page for my project in that case disabled key not working when i run the code the button is showed but i don`t want to showed until enter the values in text box, in component.ts i did connection but why button showed ?

Comment: You wrote `<button [disabled]="loginForm.valid">Enter</button>`,  you can write `<button *ngIf="loginForm.valid">Enter</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from @Eliseo: disabling !== hiding.

Disabling means to stop the button from working, which is distinctly different from not rendering the button at all.

The solution, as described, is to switch to using `*ngIf` which will cause the button to render only `IF` the condition is true.

```html
<button *ngIf="loginForm.valid">Enter</button>
```